# Is there any Tinder-like application available for Xamarin Forms that runs on IOS/Android/Windows Phone?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and i want to know how the below said feature can be done in **Xamarin.Forms** ( Target devices **android, windows phone and iphone**)

POC Feature:

1. App should be able to display a stack of 10 card in the center of the screen. At a time only one card will be shown and other cards are hidden behind the top card. We need to show that the other cards are hidden in the back.
2. Every card contains one image to the right corner, one text description beside the image and one text description to the bottom of the card.
3. User should be able to drag the top card to the left corner to skip and drag to the right corner to accept/approve the card.
4. while dragging the card, card background will change the color and it will tilt to left and right (say -25 deg left and then immediately +25 deg right)when user catches and drags it a bit either to left or right.

Please find the links below:
IPhone: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/tinder/id547702041?mt=8

I have seen the same Tinder code for ios in Xamarin.ios native, but i want to know how to do it with Xamarin.Forms which will run in all the three platforms  without issues.

Xamarin.ios example:https://components.xamarin.com/view/xcardview

Thanks
Venkat M

Answer (score 1):

If u want your answer in binary(yes/no) for all the points ,

```
1.Yes 
2.Yes
3.Yes with a condition,There is no straight forward way to achieve it , you will have to deep dive in custom renderer for each platform to achieve it.(limited support for gestures in forms without custom renderer)
4. Yes ,Again may require writing custom platform oriented code .
```

Comment: i have seen a PAN gesture added in Xamarin.Forms, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pan/, WIll this not help us to drag the card layout.

Comment: Surely, dragging can be achieved  by pan gesture ,along with rotation for tilting . ( i m trying to do it natively , if successful with post the cost)

Comment: Thank you. After doing some enough research, i could able to achieve it using Xamarin forms.